# How can I remove white spaces from source string element in Biztalk?

Tags: c#, xslt, dictionary, whitespace, biztalk

In my source schema there is an string element that I want to remove inline white space(s). 
For example: A AAAA I want to remove the second white space and string will be become AAAAA then map that to destination element.

Figure it will be challenging with built in biztalk functoids, inline C# code or xsl would work

Can anyone guide me on that?

Comment: I have no idea about Biztalk but if I would do it in C# I would split the string at ' ' (space) and then concatenate it, using trim() to be sure..

Comment: hey Erik, would you please share the code with me. It's been so long since I have codded last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, to remove *whitespace*, the generally preferred approach is something like:

```
public string removeWhitespace(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Johns-305, that worked fine too. Appreciated all of your help

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code in the Map,

```
public string removeSpace(string param1)
{
 return param1.Replace(" ", "");
}
```

Comment: Note there are more whitespace characters than just `" "`. Did you want to remove them as well?

Comment: Let says my incoming string is something like A AAAA and I want to strip the white space then it will become AAAAA and map this to destination. Above code did exactly want I wanted to accomplish.

Comment: Well, Dour High Arch has a very valid point.  The above code will remove spaces but not what is generally considered 'whitespace'.

Comment: I thought he just wanted to remove the blankspace in between the string

Comment: user2698249, you're not wrong but the question is slightly ambiguous.

Comment: @Johns-305 Hi Johns, How can I add your above regex to remove , and + characters from the string?

Comment: @Johns-305 I have 3 inputs coming as string I will need to make the format same and compare them (validate). There is an amount element in each incoming xml message 
For example for one it is +4,000 and for another one amount is coming like 4000 so I wanted to remove “+” and “comma” so they will look the same. Figured that out in C# but would be better if I can integrate this your regex.